# Can we prove that an element in a fractal tree traces back to a certain point?

Tags: hash

To know, if `D` traces back to `A` by comparing two hashes on `D` and `A`, but also know that `D` and `E` are separate branches.

```
                     D
                    /
            C ----->
           /        \
A ----- > B          E
```

I think they would need to be in a order or need some information about the time in it.

Can we prove that an element in a fractal tree traces back to a certain point?

Comment: You're about to reinvent the blockchain (like the one the Bitcoin protocol uses).

Comment: Careful—people get all excited when you say the magic word ‘blockchain’, and may accidentally dump a load of venture capital on you that you really didn't want them to.  If we have to use a technical term, a ‘Merkle tree’ or ‘Merkle DAG’ will do, like Git and Mercurial already used for years before Bitcoin existed, an idea which their creators pilfered from Monotone, whose creators probably pilfered it from someone else.  Or just ‘cryptographically hashed pointers’, or ‘authenticated data structures’, the last of which is a keyword for some literature.